# How can I make matrix multiplications faster in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization

I'm coding a simulation at the moment and optimising for speed. Looking at the line_profiler, my bottle neck lies in matrix multiplication (np.matmul). I'm performing ~800,000 different multiplications on a matrix 'A'([990, 1, 10, 3, 3]) and matrix 'B' ([990, 1, 10, 3, 1]), where A and B are different for every multiplication. Here is some 'test' code that is simplified (the matrices stay the same in this toy example, so please don't hone in on that):

```
precession = np.random.uniform(1,10,[990, 1, 10, 3, 3])
vecMblood = np.random.uniform(1,10,[990, 1, 10, 3, 1])

start = timeit.default_timer()
for _ in range(4000*200):
    np.matmul(precession, vecMblood)
end = timeit.default_timer()
print(f"np.matmul took {end - start} seconds.")
```

This takes 133 seconds on a single core. I am multithreading within my main code, that does provide some more speed--i.e. in the original code 4000 multiplications are sequential, but are independent across 200 test cases--hence these 4000 multiplications run sequentially over 12 cores for 200 cases (totalling 4000x200 (800,000)). I have also reduced the data to float32 in the main code from float64, which helped. However, it there a more optimal way of doing this within Python other than np.matmul? I have tried implementing Numba functions elsewhere too, but there is too much overhead--so I am looking for something without.

Comment: you have many small `(3,3)@(3,1)` calcs. `matmul` is basically linear in that dimension(s)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this ~40% faster by using [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) instead:

```
np.einsum("...ij,...j", precession, vecMblood[..., 0])[..., None]
```

Timings:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

a = rng.random([990, 1, 10, 3, 3])
b = rng.random(([990, 1, 10, 3, 1]))

%timeit -n 1000 np.matmul(a, b)
%timeit -n 1000 np.einsum("...ij,...j", a, b[..., 0])[..., None]
```

Output:

```
190 µs ± 10 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
108 µs ± 816 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```